# Techniques for testing code that uses multiple schedulers

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, system.reactive

When a SUT depends on multiple schedulers, what is the best way to keep the test code succinct and focussed? That is, avoid spurious calls to advance multiple different schedulers.

Until now, my technique has been to define an application-level service that provides schedulers:

```
public interface ISchedulerService
{
    IScheduler DefaultScheduler { get; }

    IScheduler SynchronizationContextScheduler { get; }

    IScheduler TaskPoolScheduler { get; }

    // other schedulers
}
```

Application components then have an instance of `ISchedulerService` injected, and for any reactive pipeline requiring a scheduler, it is obtained from the service. Test code can then use an instance of `TestSchedulerService`:

```
public sealed class TestSchedulerService : ISchedulerService
{
    private readonly TestScheduler defaultScheduler;
    private readonly TestScheduler synchronizationContextScheduler;
    private readonly TestScheduler taskPoolScheduler;
    // other schedulers

    public TestSchedulerService()
    {
        this.defaultScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        this.synchronizationContextScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        this.taskPoolScheduler = new TestScheduler();
    }

    public IScheduler DefaultScheduler
    {
        get { return this.defaultScheduler; }
    }

    public IScheduler SynchronizationContextScheduler
    {
        get { return this.synchronizationContextScheduler; }
    }

    public IScheduler TaskPoolScheduler
    {
        get { return this.taskPoolScheduler; }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        foreach (var testScheduler in this.GetTestSchedulers())
        {
            testScheduler.Start();
        }
    }

    public void AdvanceBy(long time)
    {
        foreach (var testScheduler in this.GetTestSchedulers())
        {
            testScheduler.AdvanceBy(time);
        }
    }

    public void AdvanceTo(long time)
    {
        foreach (var testScheduler in this.GetTestSchedulers())
        {
            testScheduler.AdvanceTo(time);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<TestScheduler> GetTestSchedulers()
    {
        yield return this.defaultScheduler;
        yield return this.synchronizationContextScheduler;
        yield return this.taskPoolScheduler;
        // other schedulers
    }
}
```

Test code can then control time thusly:

```
var scheduler = new TestSchedulerService();
var sut = new SomeClass(scheduler);

scheduler.AdvanceBy(...);
```

However, I've found that this can lead to a problem when the SUT uses multiple schedulers. Consider this simple example:

```
[Fact]
public void repro()
{
    var scheduler1 = new TestScheduler();
    var scheduler2 = new TestScheduler();
    var pipeline = Observable
        .Return("first")
        .Concat(
            Observable
                .Return("second")
                .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), scheduler2))
        .ObserveOn(scheduler1);
    string currentValue = null;
    pipeline.Subscribe(x => currentValue = x);

    scheduler1.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(900).Ticks);
    scheduler2.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(900).Ticks);
    Assert.Equal("first", currentValue);

    scheduler1.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100).Ticks);
    scheduler2.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100).Ticks);
    Assert.Equal("second", currentValue);
}
```

Here the SUT uses two schedulers - one controlling a delay and the other controlling which thread the subscription is observed on. This test actually fails because the schedulers are advanced in the wrong order. It doesn't matter how big the second delay (of 100ms) is - the fact that `scheduler1` is advanced before `scheduler2` means that the subscription code (controlled by `scheduler1`) won't be executed. We would need another call to advance `scheduler1` (or start it).

Obviously in the test code above, I can just swap the calls to `AdvanceBy` around and it works. However, in reality I am instead injecting my service and controlling time via it. It needs to choose a particular order for schedulers, and there's no real way to know what the "correct" order is - that depends on the SUT.

What techniques do people use to resolve this issue? I can think of these:

- Remove the time-controlling methods from the scheduler service and instead require callers to advance specific schedulers

  - Pros: forces the test code to advance schedulers in an order of their choice
  - Cons: bloats the test code and obscures intent
- Only use a single `TestScheduler` in the `TestSchedulerService` and return it from all scheduler properties

  - Pros: it solves this specific problem
  - Cons: no fine-grained control for those tests that require it
- Have the `TestSchedulerService` take a constructor argument telling it whether to create multiple `TestScheduler` instances, or just one. Default to just using one because tests that require multiple are rarer in my experience

  - Pros: solves the problem without giving up control for those tests that require it
  - Cons: a little bit magical and it complicates the `TestSchedulerService` a bit

I'm leaning towards the final option there (and have spiked out the code). But I'm wondering whether there is a clearer/cleaner way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have hinted, this is a bit of an "it depends" situation. I think your analysis is good. The `ISchedulerService` approach for DI of schedulers is sound and I have used it successfully in multiple projects.

In my personal experience, it is exceedingly rare to need multiple distinct TestSchedulers within a test - I've written well over thousand unit tests involving Rx and needed to do this on maybe five or so occasions.

So I default to using a single TestScheduler and have no particular infrastructure for managing the multiple TestScheduler scenarios.

The tests that do feature them are usually highlighting very specific edge cases and are simply carefully written and heavily commented.

I suspect that users that didn't write those tests would appreciate the details of manipulating the schedulers not being hidden behind a framework because in those situations you need to see what is happening as clearly as possible.

For that reason only I think I would stick to manipulating multiple schedulers directly in the test code where I need them.